# Efficient screen scraping in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, screen-scraping

I have some software written in C and it can screen scrape my Windows system quite well. I was wondering how I would implement some screen scraping and data capture from the windows machine in an efficient way?

Any public gems or anything else?

To clarify as requested by commenters. I am trying to be able to capture screen information using ruby - Such as scraping pixel information and other specific data (Windows GUI information)

Is there any way of doing this easily (and efficiantly) within ruby?

Cheers

Comment: You want to screen scrape your windows system? I wonder if you might mean print screen which is a different concept.

Comment: Or perhaps the OP means to control the screen, like an [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for Ruby? Terminology aside, please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question is not defined well. Please take the time to explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

[au3](http://rubygems.org/gems/au3) is a wrapper for the [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) Extension DLL file.

Answer (score 2):

One tool you can check out is [Selenium 2.0 WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html).  The tool was designed for automated testing but can be used as a simple screen scraping tool.  I hear it's a pretty great tool. Other options include [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and [Celerity](https://github.com/jarib/celerity) (jruby).  There are others. I have used Celerity with good success.

The other tool worth looking into is [Waitr](http://watir.com/).

Comment: I have had some success scraping with Nokogiri. It has some powerful search tools, most notably the xpath syntax. But it has some cool css selection syntax also.